# Find the type of a location in Android

Tags: android, location, google-places-api

Given that I have a set of location coordinates. How can I find the 'type' of that place.
Eg. Can I say that the place is a restaurant or cafe or shopping.

It would be the way Places API can tell you the type of each nearby place. Except that n my case, i want the type of the place in question.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not really clear in your question why the Places API does not satisfy your requirement. Can you just specify the latitude and longitude and set the radius to something very small?

Comment: In that case Places API would return NULL, because it wouldn't see itself in that very small radius, right? It will only try to look for places around it.

Comment: What do you mean by "wouldn't see itself"? If you specify a latitude and longitude with a radius that match up to some result, then it will return those results. If there are no results, you'll have to handle that, as not every geolocation is recorded as a "place".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the places API. Get the coordinates from the device, and make a request to the Places API with the latitude/longitude, and a very small distance (say, a matter of feet). You should probably also rank by distance, as prominence is default. Then, use the first result, as it will be your closest match, and extract the type.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests