# Android: Determining the type of the present location using the co-ordinates and address

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

Sorry if I am unclear as I did not know a better way to put my thoughts. I am working on an android application and I need to find out what kind of place the present location is. Such as is it a school, hospital, bar etc. Is there any way to achieve this? I am able to find the co-ordinates as well as the address of the location but I do not know if there is some easy way to do this.

Comment: Go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368554/find-the-type-of-a-location-in-android)

Comment: thnx @BestofhisName that is definitely helpful !!